# Is it possible to disable completely linux Redirection Operators ( <<, >>, <, >, >| )

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, operators, redhat

Is it possible to totally disallow Redirection Operators ( <<, >>, <, >, >| ) in linux, namely on a RedHat distro running bash shell?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: `bash -r` might help but it has some other side effects ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want [`rbash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) - a restricted shell.

This can be loaded in `.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile`.

> ## 6.10 The Restricted Shell
>
> If Bash is started with the name `rbash`, or the `--restricted` or `-r` option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted. A restricted shell is used to set up an environment more controlled than the standard shell. A restricted shell behaves identically to bash with the exception that the following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> - Changing directories with the `cd` builtin.
> - Setting or unsetting the values of the `SHELL`, `PATH`, `ENV`, or `BASH_ENV` variables.
> - Specifying command names containing slashes.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `.` builtin command.
> - Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the `-p` option to the hash builtin command.
> - Importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup.
> - Parsing the value of `SHELLOPTS` from the shell environment at startup.
> - Redirecting output using the `>`, `>|`, `<>`, `>&`, `&>`, and `>>` redirection operators.
> - Using the exec builtin to replace the shell with another command.
> - Adding or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin.
> - Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.
> - Specifying the `-p` option to the command builtin.
> - Turning off restricted mode with `set +r` or `set +o restricted`.
>
> These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.
>
> When a command that is found to be a shell script is executed (see [Shell Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Scripts.html#Shell-Scripts)), `rbash` turns off any restrictions in the shell spawned to execute the script.